# Create new instance of JLabel and actionlistener in loop

Tags: java, actionlistener, jlabel

I am trying to create an application launcher for my class project.

I am trying to implement a function that will take each line from a text file and put it to a `JLabel` and add an `ActionListener` each time the loop runs. At the end of the loop it did display all the `JLabels` but whenever I clicked on any it would open whatever program was last in a file.

My question is how can I make it to where I can click a program name and open the correct file?

**Here is the code I did :**

```
public static void list()
{
    String file = "files/programList.txt";

    //final Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
    String filePath;
    String content;
    String line = "";
    content = "<html>";
    int count = 0, i = 0, y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    lines = 0;
    try
    {
        FileReader read = new FileReader(file);
        LineNumberReader lRead = new LineNumberReader(
                          new FileReader(new File("files/programList.txt")));
        lRead.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(read);
        int numbOfLines = lRead.getLineNumber() + 1;
        System.out.println(numbOfLines);
        fixedLine = new ArrayList<String>(lRead.getLineNumber());
        while((line = bRead.readLine()) != null)
        {
            int index = -1;

            if(lines != numbOfLines)
            {
                if(lines == 0)
                {
                    fixedLine.add(line);
                    lines = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    fixedLine.set(lines++, line);
                    //fixedLine = line;
                    //pLine = new JLabel(fixedLine);
                    //pLine.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 1, 20));
                    //pLine.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    //pLine.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
                    //{
                    // public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                    //{
                    //  fileList.run(pLine.getText());
                    // System.out.println(pLine.getText());
                    //}
                    //});
                    //panel.add(pLine);
                    //frame.repaint();
                    //frame.revalidate();
                    content = content + line + "<br>";
                    System.out.println(lines);

                    System.out.println(fixedLine);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lines++;
            }
        }
        bRead.close();
        lRead.close();
        content = content + "</html>";
        System.out.println(fixedLine.get(0));

        System.out.println(numbOfLines);//maybe use array or arraylist
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I was experimenting with an string arraylist and only got it to add one program before it gives me an error.

What can I do to get it working?

After I get the program working I will simplify my code and improve it as I know my coding isn't the best

Comment: `before it gives me an error`, if you want people to help with the error you´re getting, show them the error you are getting

Comment: don't really understand what you're trying, but first replace the fixedLine.set(..) with  fixedLine.add(..) to avoid an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @clic I've tried that before and it would always just put the last line of the text file in the array. I've tried putting the fixedLine.add() before the while loop so there would be something in the array while in the loop, and as seen in the code tried an if statement. I haven't worked with many arrays before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to execute something when you click a JLabel, something read from a file. I think you do strange things to read the lines. Why so many lists? You could do something like

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("files", "programList.txt")).forEach(
            f -> {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(f);
                label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        executeopeningMagicWithTheFile(f);
                    }
                });
                panel.add(label);
            }
    );
```

I hope this helps, it's rather unclear what exactly you want since your code contains code in comment and variables that are not defined

Comment: Would this replace everything in the try statement? Sorry about all the comments, I was in the middle of implementing the ArrayList and commented out all the code I knew partly worked so I can go back to the old way if needed.

Comment: Yes it would replace that.